# Make active class triangle slide using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Im trying to get a downward arrow to slide to the active div much like the squarespace website: http://www.squarespace.com/about/contact.

So far I have gotten the arrow to appear on the active, clicked div fine using css and jquery however I would like the arrow to slide to the active div and not just appear and disappear using addClass and removeClass.

Any help would be much appreciated!

CSS for active arrow:

```
  .arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.arrow_box.active:after {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-top-color: #111;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    z-index: 2000;

}
```

Jquery to add arrow active class to clicked div:

```
 $('#click').click(function(){
    $(".arrow_box").removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");

 $('#click2').click(function(){
    $(".arrow_box").removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");

 $('#click3').click(function(){
    $(".arrow_box").removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
```

HTML:

```
<div  id="click" class="four columns arrow_box active">
    <h5 class="center whitetext thin">GENERAL</h5>

</div>
<div id="click2" class="four columns arrow_box">
    <h5 class="center whitetext thin">USERS</h5>

</div>
<div id="click3" class="four columns arrow_box">
    <h5 class="center whitetext thin">AGENTS</h5>

</div>
```

I resolved this by placing a single arrow_box under the divs and then used .animate() to move the arrow under the respective, active div. Simple in the end!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: Sorry I should have done that to start with it, but I've just figured it out. I placed a single arrow under the divs and then used .animate() to move the arrow under the respective, active div.